# An $\ell^qL^p$ inequality: $\|\nabla\langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}\varphi\|_{\ell^2L^4}\leq \|{\varphi}\|_{L^2}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

An $\ell^qL^p$ inequality: $\|\nabla\langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}\varphi\|_{\ell^2L^4}\leq \|{\varphi}\|_{L^2}$. The dimensions I care about are $d=2$ and $d=3$.

We define $\ell^qL^p$ in the following way. For $\alpha\in \mathbb Z^d$, let $\square_\alpha$ be the unit cube in $\mathbb R^d$ with centre at $\alpha$ and let $\chi_\alpha$ be its characteristic function.

Define $\ell^q(L^p)$ to be the set of functions for which $$\|{f}\|_{\ell^qL^p}:=\left({\sum_\alpha\|{f\chi_\alpha}\|^q_{L^p}}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}=\left({\sum_\alpha\left({\int_{\square_\alpha}|{f(x)}|^p\mathrm{d}x}\right)^{\frac{p}{q}}}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$is finite.

The question says to use the Hölder inequality and the Sobolev inequality.

Idea of proof:

Using $L^p$ interpolation, $\frac{1}{4}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{2}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\infty}$, so \begin{align*}\|\nabla\langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}\varphi\|_{\ell^2L^4}= \left({\sum_\alpha\|{\nabla\langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}\varphi\chi_\alpha}\|^2_{L^4}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}&\leq\|\nabla\langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}\varphi\|_{L^\infty}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left({\sum_\alpha\|{\nabla\langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}\varphi\chi_\alpha}\|^2_{L^2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= \|\nabla\langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}\varphi\|_{L^\infty}^{\frac{1}{2}}\|\nabla\langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}\varphi\|_{L^2}^{\frac{1}{2}}.\end{align*}

Now $\|\nabla\langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}\varphi\|_{L^2}\leq\|\varphi\|_{L^2}$ which is easily seen on the Fourier side. I'm not sure how to prove $\|\nabla\langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}\varphi\|_{L^\infty}$ is bounded by $\|\varphi\|_{L^2}$ (I'm not even sure if this is true).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by $\langle \nabla \rangle^{-2} \varphi$ here?

Comment: It is usually a notation for $(1-\Delta)^{-1}\varphi$. I suppose you should use the fact that by Sobolev inequality $\|\nabla\langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}\varphi\|_{L^p(\square)} \leq\|\varphi\|_{L^2}$ where $p = 2^* > 2$, so you should rather interpolate between $L^2$ and $L^p$.

Comment: So $\psi = \langle \nabla \rangle^{-2} \varphi$ is the solution to $(1-\Delta)\psi  = \varphi$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$. But then there is little hope to write local inequalities. Like, do you intend to use the $L^2(\square)$ norm on the RHS in your estimate?

Comment: @cs89 Define $\langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}$ to be an operator on $L^2$ such that $\widehat{\langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}\varphi}(\xi)=\langle\xi\rangle^{-2}\widehat\varphi(\xi)$, where $\langle\xi\rangle=\sqrt{1+|\xi|^2}$, for all $\varphi\in L^2$

Comment: @LL3.14 Yes I think that's the right idea, but we need to use the Sobolev inequality on a bounded domain in order to not have an infinite sum. Does this work? By the Sobolev embedding theorem, we have $\|{f}\|_{L^4(\square_\alpha)}\leq C(|\square|)\|{f}\|_{H^s(\square_\alpha)}$ if $s=d/4$. We will need that $s\leq1$, so $d\leq 4$.

Comment: Therefore\begin{align*}
    \|{\nabla\langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}\varphi_j}\|^2_{\ell^2 L^4}\lesssim\|{\nabla\langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}\varphi_j}\|^2_{\ell^2 H^s}=\|{\nabla\langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}\varphi_j}\|_{H^s(\mathbb R^d)}^2=\int \|{\langle{\xi}\rangle^s|{\xi}|\langle{\xi}\rangle^{-2}\widehat\varphi_j(\xi)}|^2\,d\xi\leq\|{\varphi_j}\|_{L^2}^2
\end{align*}if $s\leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

By defining $\psi := (1-\Delta)^{-1}\varphi = \langle\nabla\rangle^{-2}\varphi$, then $\varphi = (1-\Delta)\psi$ and your inequality can be written
$$
\|\nabla\psi\|_{\ell^2L^4} \leq \|(1-\Delta)\psi\|_{L^2}.
$$
Let me first take $d\geq 3$ and $p = \frac{2\,d}{d-2}$. Since $2\leq 4\leq p$, by Hölder's inequality, for any unit cube $\square$
$$
\|\nabla\psi\|_{L^4(\square)} \leq \|\nabla\psi\|_{L^2(\square)}^{\theta} \|\nabla\psi\|_{L^p(\square)}^{1-\theta}
$$
where $\theta = \frac{p-4}{2(p-2)}$ (i.e. $\frac{1}{4} = \frac{\theta}{2}+\frac{(1-\theta)}{p}$).
Then the Sobolev inequality tells that
$$
\|\nabla\psi\|_{L^p(\square)} \leq C_d\,\|\nabla\psi\|_{H^1(\square)},
$$
and so we deduce that
$$
\|\nabla\psi\|_{L^4(\square)} \leq C_d\,\|\nabla\psi\|_{L^2(\square)}^{\theta} \|\nabla\psi\|_{H^1(\square)}^{1-\theta} \leq C_d\, \|\nabla\psi\|_{H^1(\square)}.
$$
Taking the squares on both sides, then the sum over all the cubes and then the square root yields
$$
\|\nabla\psi\|_{\ell^2L^4} \leq C_d\, \|\nabla\psi\|_{H^1}.
$$
It remains to notice that
$$
\|\nabla\psi\|_{H^1}^2 \leq \|(1-\Delta)\psi\|_{H^1}^2
$$
as can be easily seen from the Fourier definition of $H^1$ for example. In dimension $d\leq 2$, the Sobolev inequality still works from $H^1$ to any $L^p$ with $p\in[2,\infty)$.